# How to getting dimensions from STL file?

Tags: c#

I have an binary format STL (STereoLithography) file, I have successfully read the file from c#.net and got the facets, I also got the count of triangles, volume of the part and surface area of the part. But now the problem is that I am not able to find the dimensions of the 3D object(Length,breadth,height). Please help.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I need, but I'm far behind you.
How did u get the facets? Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will probably have to calculate this yourself, but the algorithm should be fairly simple, assuming you want the dimensions in x,y,z rather than some rotation. Loop through the facets to find the max and min x,y and z coordinate values. Then the dimensions are simply the differences between max and min.

Edit: you could keep track of the max/min values while reading in the points from the file for a minor performance boost.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Hint. I got the dimensions. Now I need to find number of Parts present in the STL file and layer thickness, can you please suggest.

Comment: what number have you got? i just get numbers like +-"1.08717837E+9" do you know why?